# Chilkat CkHttpResponse statusLine() Method is Buggy

Tags: c++, chilkat

Assume the following HTTP response with the HTTP Status Line **Reason** phrase **ending with a space** (There's a white space \x20 character after the "OK" reason phrase):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Sun, 29 Feb 2010 15:14:06 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Querying a server with such a response using the following Chilkat code snippet,

```
// other stuff
CkHttpResponse* resp;
// other stuff
std::cout << resp->statusLine();
```

yields this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
```

The response header parser is taking the first header after the Status Line as part of the status line string!

I couldn't find any reference to this behaviour in the RFC.

Note: I've tested it with the latest version, v9.5.0.97.

@chilkat-software

Comment: Looks like a bug in a closed-source proprietary library.  Who knew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 7230:

```
status-line = HTTP-version SP status-code SP reason-phrase CRLF
reason-phrase  = *( HTAB / SP / VCHAR / obs-text )
```

The status line `HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n` is valid if you ensure it ends with `\r\n` (we can't see it in the question).
In this case, Chilkat `CkHttpResponse` seems to be buggy.

If otherwise the status line is `HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n`, then the server software is buggy.

Comment: I confirm that the status line in the above example ends with `\n` and not `\r\n`. But, why would Chilkat CkHttpResponse take the first header after the Status Line as part of the status line string? Does it mean that it keeps reading the response headers until it finds the first `\r\n`? In this case, the header `Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0` indeed ends with `\r\n`.

Comment: *Does it mean that it keeps reading the response headers until it finds the first `\r\n`?* - Yes, it does. This is the only valid message field end.